# How to solve the error in the following program which is written Functional Programming way?

Tags: python

Question: Write a program that reads table with given columns from input stream. Columns are name, amount, debt. Then filter the table (condition: debt is equal to 0). After that increase debt by 42% then print results.

I am a beginner in Python and have tried multiple times but still couldn't fixed the problem. Help will be much appreciated.

```
   Input:
   10
   Tatiana Santos 411889 36881
   Yuvraj Holden 121877 0
   Theia Nicholson 783887 591951
   Raife Padilla 445511 0
   Hamaad Millington 818507 276592
   Maksim Whitehead 310884 0
   Iosif Portillo 773233 0
   Lachlan Daniels 115100 0
   Evie-Grace Reese 545083 0
   Ashlea Cooper 68771 0

  Required Output:
  Tatiana Santos  411889 52371.02
  Theia Nicholson 783887 840570.42
  Hamaad Millington 818507 392760.64

  My Solution: 



  def input_data(n):
      tup = []
      if n>0:
         tup.append(tuple(map(str,input().split(" "))))
      input_data(n-1) #I know there's a problem in the recursion. I am not #doing anything with the return value. Please help
      return tup 


  def filtertuple(* tup): # After debugged I got to know at this point only one row is passed to function 
            


    newtuple = filter(lambda i: i[2]!=0,tup)

  return tuple(newtuple)


  def increasedebt(newtuple):  

    newtuple1 = tuple(map(lambda i:(i[2])*(142/100)),newtuple)

  return (newtuple1)
 
  def output_data():

    n=int(input())
    return n

  print(increasedebt(filtertuple(input_data(output_data()))))





  Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\msi-pc\PycharmProjects\ProgramminglanguageTask3\main.py", 
  line 28, in <module>
  print(increasedebt(filtertuple(input_data(output_data()))))
  File "C:\Users\msi-pc\PycharmProjects\ProgramminglanguageTask3\main.py", 
  line 14, in filtertuple
  return tuple(newtuple)
  File "C:\Users\msi-pc\PycharmProjects\ProgramminglanguageTask3\main.py", 
  line 12, in <lambda>
  newtuple = filter(lambda i: i[2] != 0, tup)
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Mureinik The question is :Write a program that reads table with given columns from input stream. Columns are name, amount, debt. Then filter the table (condition: debt is equal to 0). After that increase debt by 42% then print results.   I have written the above code for the same in functional programming way. But I am getting error and I debugged the code and found that when I am return tuple(tup) in first function, and when passing to next function it only passes the first item of tup.

Comment: It seems to go wrong out `output_data()` already. There you convert the user input to one integer.

Comment: just cast tuple to list

Comment: Why are you using `def filtertuple(*tup)` as the function signature? That means your function takes variadic positional arguments. Just make it take a single positional argument because that is how you are using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two main issues with how your code passes the data from `input_data` to `filtertuple`.

The first issue is that your recursion in `input_data` is messed up, you never do anything with the results of the recursive calls so only the first row of input data gets included in the final return value. Recursion really isn't an ideal approach to this problem, a loop would be a lot simpler and cleaner. But you *could* make the recursion work, if you do something with the value returned to you, like `tup.extend(intput_data(n-1))`. If you stick with recursion, you'll also need to make the base case return something appropriate (or add an extra check for `None`), like an empty list (or tuple).

The second issue is that `filtertuple` is written to expect many arguments, but you're only passing it one. So `tup` will always be a 1-tuple containing the actual argument. If you're expecting the one argument to be a list of tuples (or tuple of tuples, I'm not sure exactly what API you're aiming for), you shouldn't use `*tup` in the argument list, just `tup` is good without the star. You *could* call `filtertuple(*input_data(...))` which would unpack your tuple of tuples into many arguments, but that would be silly if the function is just going to pack them back up into `tup` again.

There may be other issues further along in the code, I was only focused on the `input_data` and `filtertuple` interactions, since that's what you were asking about.

Here's my take on solving your problem:

```
def gather_data(num_lines):
    if num_lines == 0:  # base case
        return []       # returns an empty list

    data = gather_data(num_lines-1)     # recursive case, always gives us a list

    row = tuple(map(int, input().split(" ")))  # get one new row
    data.append(row)                           # add it to the existing list

    return data

def filter_zeros(data):   # note, we only expect one argument (a list of tuples)
    return list(filter(lambda i: i[1] != 0, data))

def adjust_debt(data):    # this only returns a single column, should it return
    return list(map(lambda i: (i[1]) * (142 / 100), data))   # the whole table?

# calling code:
num_lines = int(input())  # this code really didn't deserve its own function
data = gather_data(num_lines)    # extra variables help debugging
filtered = filter_zeros(data)    # but they could be dropped later
adjusted = adjust_debt(filtered)
print(adjusted)
```

I did find one extra issue, you had the parentheses wrong in the function I renamed to `adjust_debt`.

Comment: I know I am wrong in many places. But I am very new to python. And I am trying to do this in python in functional programming way so I feel it's becoming difficult.  And you are right, when I tried to print the *tup, I can see only one row but instead I want all the rows to pass to the filtertuple function. Can please answer specifically what should I do exactly so that whatever I am returning from first function should be able to pass in the filtertuple function so that I can filter the rows.  I tried doing what you mentioned above but failed.